# Equality with matrix exponential, sine and cosine

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

For a square matrix $X$, $e^X$ is given by the power series $$e^X = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{1 \over k!}X^k.$$

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-w^2&-a_0\\\end{bmatrix}.$$ Verify that $$e^{At}=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\xi}\{(\xi\cos(\xi t)+\lambda\sin(\xi t))I+A\sin(\xi t)\},$$ where $\lambda=\frac{a_0}{2}$ and $\xi=\left(w^2-\frac{a_0^2}{4}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$.

How should I attack this?

Comment: Try writing a few powers of $A$ out and see what pattern comes out of it. Then use induction.

Comment: Try diagonalization!

Comment: The eigenvalues will be the same as the roots to the polynomial it's a (transposed) companion matrix for. You can find the coefficients of that polynomial right in the matrix, it's a second degree one so it's easy to solve too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some (hopefully useful) preliminaries

1. In general, if $A$ is diagonalizable then $A = U\Lambda U^{-1}$ with $U$ the matrix containing the eigenvectors as columns and $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix formed with the eigenvalues $\Lambda = {\rm diag}\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots \}$. Furthermore

   $$
    A^k = \underbrace{(U\Lambda U^{-1}) \cdots (U\Lambda U^{-1})}_{k ~{\rm times}} = U\Lambda^k U^{-1}\tag{1}
    $$
2. Taking this into account

   $$
    e^{t A} = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^k }{k!}A^k \stackrel{(1)}{=} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^k }{k!}U\Lambda^kU^{-1} = U\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^k }{k!}\Lambda^k\right)U^{-1} = Ue^{t\Lambda}U^{-1} \tag{2}
    $$

   with $e^{t\Lambda} = {\rm diag}\{e^{t\lambda_1},e^{t\lambda_2},\cdots \}$

> Now the problem

In this case, diagonalizing the matrix $A$ is pretty straightforward with, with

$$
\Lambda = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
-\lambda - i\xi & 0 \\
0 & -\lambda + i\xi 
\end{array}\right) ~~~\mbox{and}~~~
U= \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
(-\lambda + i\xi)/\omega^2 & (-\lambda - i\xi)/\omega^2 \\
1 & 1 
\end{array}\right)
$$

The inverse of  $U$ can also be obtained

$$
U^{-1}= \frac{1}{2i\xi}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
\omega^2 & \lambda + i\xi \\
-\omega^2 & -\lambda + i\xi
\end{array}\right)
$$

Evaluating into Eq. (2) we get

\begin{eqnarray}
e^{t\Lambda} &=& Ue^{t\Lambda}U^{-1} \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\xi}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \lambda  \sin (t \xi )+\xi  \cos (t \xi ) & \underbrace{\omega^{-2}\left(\lambda ^2+\xi
   ^2\right)}_{\color{red}{1}} \sin (t \xi ) \\
 -\omega ^2 \sin (t \xi ) & \xi  \cos (t \xi )\underbrace{-\lambda}_{\color{red}{\lambda - 2\lambda = \lambda -a_0}}  \sin (t \xi )
\end{array}
\right) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\xi}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \lambda  \sin (t \xi )+\xi  \cos (t \xi ) &  \sin (t \xi ) \\
 -\omega ^2 \sin (t \xi ) & \xi  \cos (t \xi )+\lambda  \sin (t \xi ) -a_0\sin(t \xi) 
\end{array} 
\right) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\xi}\left\{(\lambda  \sin (t \xi )+\xi  \cos (t \xi )) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) + \sin (t\xi) 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -\omega^2 & -a_0
\end{array}
\right)\right\} \\
&=& \frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{\xi}\left\{(\lambda  \sin (t \xi )+\xi  \cos (t \xi )) I + \sin (t\xi)  A\right\} 
\end{eqnarray}